# Confusion Between Likelihood and Probability

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand and sort-out a confusion I have always had regarding Probability.

As I understand, the probability density function $f_X(x)$ of a **Continuous Random Variable** $X$ is a function that satisfies the following properties:

- $f_X(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. the probability density function is non-negative;
- $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) dx = 1$, i.e. the total area under the probability density function is equal to 1;
- for any interval $[a,b]$, the probability that $X$ lies in that interval is given by $\int_{a}^{b} f_X(x) dx$.

Although this fact is usually taken for granted - the probability that $X$ takes on any specific value $x$  is zero: $P(X=x) = \int_{x}^{x} f(t) \ dt = 0$.

When it comes to the concept of Likelihood -  if we assume that some "Observed Sequence of Events" were to come from some probability distribution function   $f_X(x;\theta)$ - we can write the Joint Likelihood of this "Observing some Sequence of Events" from this Probability Distribution Function as:

$$L(\theta|x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_X(x_i;\theta) = f_X(x_1;\theta) \cdot f_X(x_2;\theta) \cdot \ldots \cdot f_X(x_n;\theta).$$

As a result, maximizing this Likelihood Function leads us to the "most likely" parameters $\theta$ of $ f_X(x_i;\theta)$ that would generate some sequence of events  $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$:

$$\frac{d}{d\theta} L(\theta|x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = \frac{d}{d\theta} \left[\prod_{i=1}^n f_X(x_i;\theta)\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d}{d\theta} \ln f_X(x_i;\theta) = 0.$$

**Here is my confusion:**

Informally, we are told that we can think that the Joint Likelihood of observing some sequence of events can be thought of as the "Joint Probability" of observing this sequence of events. However, to me this appears to be a contradiction because the probability of observing a single event from a probability distribution is 0 by definition - **therefore, the joint probability of observing a series of single events must also be 0.**

This fact also becomes apparent when we see that the Joint Likelihood Function is not always between 0 and 1 - yet Joint Probability must always be between 0 and 1.

**However, when we consider Discrete Random Variables, this appears to be true - the Joint Probability is equal to the Joint Likelihood .**

Suppose $X$ is a **Discrete Random Variable** that can take on values from 1 to k, and let $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ be a sequence of n observations of $X$.The joint probability mass function of observing this sequence is given by:

$$p(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = P(X = x_1 \cap X = x_2 \cap ... \cap X = x_n)$$

The joint likelihood function of observing this same sequence is given by:

$$L(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n | \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} p(x_i|\theta)$$

where $\theta$ is the parameter(s) of the probability mass function of X.

For a given sequence of observations $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$, the joint probability of observing this sequence is equal to the joint likelihood of observing the same sequence:

$$ p(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = L(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n | \theta) $$

**Therefore, in the discrete case, maximizing the joint likelihood function $L(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n | \theta)$ with respect to $\theta$ appears to be directly equivalent to maximizing the joint probability mass function $p(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$.**

Can someone please help me understand this? In the continuous random variable case - why are we told that evaluating the joint product of probability distributions at specific values (i.e. joint likelihood) represents the idea of joint probabilities?

Thanks!

Comment: Much as the PDF for a single random variable is not a probability, but rather a probability density, the product of a bunch of pdfs is not a joint probability, but rather a joint probability density.

Comment: Heuristically, the density is a measure of intensity of concentration of mass. Recall that the density is given by differentiating the CDF. Hence $P(X\in[t,t+h])\approx hf_X(t)$

Comment: Statistics is not a science, it is an art. To me maximizing $L(\theta,x)$ in this way is quite an intuitive and viable method to find the unknown parameter $\theta$ that explains the made observations assuming their "real" distribution is in the class $f(x,\theta)$. Statistical data are typically (if not always) discrete. This does not forbid a model $f(x,\theta)$ for them that is continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies everyone!