# Truncating the pdf function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Sorry for the naive question, but I can't figure out the answer to.

**Edited for clarity**

I have a dataset  and I'm sampling from this dataset, evaluating the samples on my normal distribution $P$ pdf and feed the calculated probability value to function .  requires that the probability values should be lower and upper bounder by (,) and I'm allowed to transform $P$ to get it between bounds. My question is, can I transform  in a way that it would be upper and lower bounded?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "that truncates the support not the likelihood," but the inputs of $f$ are the samples, not the distribution function, right?  So you just need that the support of the distribution you are sampling from is upper bounded by $\gamma$.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @user6247850 right, my question was not clear enough. I need to pass the sample and it's logprob value to the function and the function requires that the likelihood of each sample be upper bounded. My question is, is there a way to transform a pdf so that the likelihood is upper and lower bounded?

Comment: Hint: if $p(x)$ is a pdf on $(-\infty,+\infty)$ which is the factor $c$ that makes $cp(x)1_{(a,b)}(x)$ a pdf ?

Comment: @KurtG. um the pdf should be positive and integrate to 1. So we need to have a factor $c$ greater than 1 to fix the integral of our transformed pdf function?

Comment: $c$ will come out greater than $1$. That's not a problem at all, or is it?

Comment: @KurtG. I'm almost sure I'm misinterpreting your hints. The factor $c$ in and of itself shouldn't have any requirements. Then again, if you just multiply $c$ with the transformed pdf you'd get likelihood values higher than your upper bound. One way I can think of is to "stretch" the probability mass so that it falls under the upper bound - like adjusting the variance in a normal distribution- but then the transformed pdf function is a true pdf and we won't be needing the factor $c$. Sorry I'm a bit lost here

Comment: My hints can only be as good as your question. There is no doubt that if you want to restrict a pdf to an interval you do it as I wrote. How a likelihodd is related to a pdf is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4656005/949989). Technically likelihood *is* a pdf. You should povide more context and formulas to enable better hints or answers.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  What you appear to be saying is that you have a function $\ f:\mathbb{R}\times[0,\gamma\,]\rightarrow Y\ $ (with $\ Y\ $ as yet unspecified) and a sample $\ x\ $ from some normal distribution  $\ \mathcal{N}\big(\mu,\sigma^2\big)\ $, and you want to apply $\ f\ $ to the pair $\ x,P_x\ $, where $\ P_x=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\ $ is the likelihood function evaluated at $\ x\ $.  Is that correct?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera yes. To make things simpler, let's say that I have a dataset $\mathbf{X}$ and I'm sampling from this dataset, evaluating the samples on my normal distribution $P$ pdf and feed the calculated probability value to function $f$. $f$ requires that the probability values should be lower and upper bounder by $\phi,\gamma$ and I'm allowed to transform P or if needed replace it with any other pdf I want. My question is, can I transform $P$ in a way that it would be upper and lower bounded?

Comment: @Bahar Az Presumably, if you replace the normal distribution with any other, then your samples would have to be drawn from that other distribution, rather than the original normal distribution?  Otherwise, I can't see how substituting a sample from a normal distribution and a probability density value from a *completely different* distribution into $\ f\ $ could serve any useful purpose.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera yes exactly! That is why I went with a Gaussian distribution so I can understand how I can systematically bound the probability values without doing something hacky like just clipping them.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\eqdef{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
It's easy to transform any distribution with a density that's bounded into one that's bounded above by a specific upper bound $\ \gamma\ $.

Let $\ F\ $ be any cumulative distribution function with density function $\ \xi\ $ satisfying $\ \sup_\limits{x\in\mathbb{R}} \xi(x)\le u\ $. Then $$G(x)\eqdef F\left(\frac{\gamma x}{u}\right)$$ defines a cumulative distribution function whose density, $\ \frac{\gamma}{u}\xi\left(\frac{\gamma x}{u}\right)\ $, will be bounded above by $\ \gamma\ $.

The maximum value of the density of a normal distribution with mean $\ \mu\ $ and variance $\ \sigma^2\ $ is $\ \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\ $, so you can ensure that $\ \gamma\ $ will be an upper bound for the density simply by choosing $\ \sigma\ge\frac{1}{\gamma\sqrt{2\pi}}\ $.

The lower bound is more problematic if it's required to be positive.  If $\ \phi>0\ $, then it's impossible for any density function $\ \xi\ $ to satisfy $\ \inf_\limits{x\in\mathbb{R}} \xi(x)\ge\phi\ $, because $\ \xi\ $ must also satisfy
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\xi(x)\,dx=1\ .
$$
The best you can do is ensure that the density of a distribution *with finite support* is bounded below by $\ \phi\ $ *over that support*.  *Outside the support*, the density will, of course, be identically zero, and it must have jump discontinuities at the limits of the support.

The simplest distribution whose density had lower and upper bounds of $\ \phi\ $ and $\ \gamma\ $ over its support is a uniform distribution over an interval of length $\ \frac{1}{v}\ $, where $\ \phi\le v\le\gamma\ $.  The density of such a distribution will have a constant value $\ v\ $ over the interval, and vanish outside it.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. I really appreciate the reply and sorry for the confusing formulation of the problem. This is clear and really helpful. Unfortunately I can't accept this as an answer since I don't have enough reputation :) maybe one of the admins can do it.